# How can I get values from jQuery dialog box which has 2 text boxes? Can I store them in a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried jQuery, but I am not able to get values from that dialog box.
Is there any way that I could store those values in a JavaScript variable (i.e., coming from jQuery dialog).

```
<div id="dialog-message2">

  <center><p>
    What percentage would you like to refund?</br>
    <input type="text" id="per" name="per" > %
    </p></center>

    <center><p>
    Reason: <input type="text" id="reason" name="reason" >
    </p></center>


    <br><center><input type="submit" id="proceed" name="proceed" value="PROCEED" style='width:60px;height:30px;background-color:#0066CC;color:#FFFAF0; -webkit-border-radius: 9px'></center>
</div>
```

Or is there any other method in JavaScript?

Comment: See Dialog modal form : https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: just a side note : you don't have to ask entire question in title itself mate!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#proceed").click(function(){

    //using JQuery
    var perValue = $("#per").val();
    var reasonValue = $("#reason").val();
    console.log(reasonValue);
    console.log(perValue);
    });    
});

//using javascript
document.getElementById('proceed').onclick = Onclick;
function Onclick(){
    var reasonValue = document.getElementById("reason").value;    
    var perValue = document.getElementById("per").value;
    console.log(reasonValue);
    console.log(perValue);
}
```

I have included Jquery and normal javascript based on the onlick function of the button.  You can test it out on this: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AJV47/4/).  You can check you console to see the output of the var values.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var something = document.getElementById("yourIDhere").value;
```